# Postgres Stored Procedure issue - how do I solve this?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I am creating a stored procedure that looks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_components(_given_user_id integer) RETURNS TABLE (id integer, name    varchar, active boolean, parent integer, type smallint, description varchar, email varchar, user_id integer, component_id integer, flag smallint) AS $body$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY SELECT s.* FROM st_components s LEFT JOIN (SELECT a.* FROM st_users_components_perms a WHERE a.user_id=_given_user_id) ON a.component_id=s.id ORDER BY name;
END;
$body$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The problem is, ON a.component_id=s.id ORDER BY name doesn't work because a.component_id is out of scope at this point. Is there a way to declare "a" as st_users_components_perms outside of the query? How is this solved? Thank you very much for any insight!

Comment: Welcome to SO. There is no point in a `LEFT JOIN` if you are not going to use the joined table in any way. If your function is the real deal, the declaration could be simplified, too. Aside from that, please format with line breaks. Hard to read this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    s.*
FROM
    st_components s
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
        a.*
    FROM
        st_users_components_perms a
  WHERE
      a.user_id = <CONSTANT>
    ) AS x
ON
    x.component_id = s.id
ORDER BY
    name;
```

Though the query seems pointless but let's assume it's a simplified version of your real query.